# JSONRPC on Android does not POST

Tags: android, json-rpc

I have the following code:

```
JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
jsonRequest.put("id", 1);
jsonRequest.put("method", "mymethod");
entity = new JSONEntity(jsonRequest);
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.103/foo/bar.php");
request.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

*Irrelevant code removed*

It posts to a .php page. On the .php page I call `var_dump` to check the content of both $_POST and $_GET. Both are empty.

Any idea?

Comment: localhost point to android emulator/device not to the host of emulator use my_computer_name or ip address instead

Comment: correct, but thats not the problem. I have that setup correctly in the actual code. I edited my question.

Comment: try HttpGet("http://192.168.1.103/foo/bar.php?id=1&method=mymethod") i think $_POST/$_GET is for form or query string not for json

Comment: Yes, that will work. Its not the awnser I'm looking for because I'm pretty sure that there must be a way to post the JSONEntity. But atleast I can continue development using your approach.

Comment: i don't know PHP but what u need is reading the "file" ({"id":1, "method":"mymethod"}) whith was sensed from android and parse it in some kinde of json API in PHP

Comment: The PHP server does not receive anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Obtain the data in php:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
```